# ReferenceError: list is not defined Potsman error

Tags: javascript, json, postman-testcase

I am executing below script in Postman and getting error **"ReferenceError: list is not defined "**

```
response = pm.response.json(responseBody)
console.log(response)
token = response.provider-list[6].user-list[1].activation-token
console.log(token)
```

I am trying to extract a vaule from JSON response body and my JSON path is
$.provider-list[6].user-list[1].activation-token

Comment: `-` is the subtraction operator. So you're trying to subtract `list[6]` from `response.provider`

Comment: If the key is `provider-list` you need to write `response['provider-list']`

Comment: I get a syntax error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
)when try that way
token = response.[provider-list][6].[user-list][1].[activation-token]

Comment: No `.` before `[`

Comment: And you need quotes around `provider-list` and `user-list`. Did you read the linked question?

Comment: same error without '.'

Comment: Did you add the quotes like I said?

Comment: Please edit the question and show what you really tried, and paste the exact error message.

Comment: `token = response['provider-list'][6]['user-list'][1]['activation-token']`

Comment: Thanks a lot..It fixed the issue.